# Error with Angular 2 Template

Tags: html, angular, templates

I am using an Angular 2 template (which looks fine to me):

```js
<div class="container gt-container-fluid gt-container-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <fieldset class="gt-fieldset">
                <legend class="gt-legend">Details</legend>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-6"><label for="title">Requirements Title:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><input id="title" type="text" class="k-textbox" [(ngModel)]="Requirement.Title" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-12"><label for="details">Requirements Details:</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <textarea id="details" class="k-textbox gt-textbox" [(ngModel)]="Requirement.Details"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-6"><label for="rating">Requirement Rating:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><kendo-dropdownlist id="ratings" [data]="ratingsData" [textField]="'ProductName'" [valueField]="'ProductID'" [defaultItem]="ratingsPlaceHolder"></kendo-dropdownlist></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-6"><label for="status">Approval Status:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-6"><kendo-dropdownlist id="approvalStatus" [data]=""></kendo-dropdownlist></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="gt-fieldset">
                <legend class="gt-legend">Attachments</legend>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-12"><label for="attachments">Drag and drop files of click "Select" to browse:</label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gt-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <kendo-upload id="Attachments"
                                      [saveUrl]=""
                                      [removeUrl]=""
                                      [disabled]="">
                        </kendo-upload>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <kendo-tabstrip>
                <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Framework Items'" [selected]="true">
                    <template kendoTabContent>
                        <div class="row gt-row">
                            <div class="col-6"><label for="framework">Framework Items:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-6"><kendo-multiselect [data]="frameworkItems" [value]="" [placeholder]="'Framework Items'"></kendo-multiselect></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row gt-row">
                            <div class="col-12 gt-col-addremovebuttons">
                                <button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="true">+</button>
                                <button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="true">-</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row gt-row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <kendo-grid [data]="frameworkItemsData" [height]="200">
                                    <kendo-grid-column field="FrameworkLocation" title="ID">
                                    </kendo-grid-column>
                                    <kendo-grid-column field="FrameworkTitle" title="Name">
                                    </kendo-grid-column>
                                </kendo-grid>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
                <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Related Actions'">
                    <template kendoTabContent>
                        <div class="row gt-row">
                            <div class="col-6"><label for="actions">Related Actions:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-6"><kendo-multiselect [data]="actionItems" [value]="" [placeholder]="'Actions'"></kendo-multiselect></div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
            </kendo-tabstrip>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row gt-row">
        <div class="col-12 gt-col-buttons">
            <button kendoButton (click)="saveChanges()" [primary]="true">Save</button>
            <button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="false">Edit</button>
            <button kendoButton (click)="deleteRecord()" [primary]="false">Delete</button>
            <button kendoButton (click)="onButtonClick()" [primary]="false">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, it is throwing the following error (amongst others):

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing
>   tag "legend" (">\n            \n
>   Details[ERROR ->]\n
>   \n                    \n                    Requirements Title:[ERROR ->]\n
>   \n

Interestingly the code highlighting in the code input in stack overflow shows me the same kind of errors but I can't for the life of me spot the error.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The HTML all looks okay to me, so not sure why you are getting that template erorr. Or at least I can't tell with what is provided. I would suggest trying to create a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve